# What does the yellow background on filename mean in Intellij?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I think it might have something to do with asynchronous tasks but I don't know for sure. Could someone please clarify this for me?

Also what do the yellow frames mean when you are debugging?

[image]

Comment: This happenned in a new Angular project for me but looks like the language doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This color indicates the **non-project files** (libraries), you can customize it here:

[image: non-project files]

Make sure to restart the debugger for the changes to have effect.

Comment: My files used to be project files and sudenly turned to be non-project files. After a PyCharm update, looks like it's a bug

Answer (score 61):

If this suddenly happens to your project:
Consider closing pycharm and deleting the `.idea/` folder of that project.

After reopening the project the project, pycharm will detect all files as normal.
But you'll need to set up the project again.
-> Set source-folder, add run configuration etc.

For me that was the faster solution than figuring out how to fix it.

One more mention: It happened after a merge which caused some version conflicts and required to "roll back" a file.

Comment: thanks. I was deleting `.idea` directory inside intellij. You need to make sure to close intellij first and then delete the directory.

Comment: this solution helped me in webstorm IDE

Comment: Great, this works also for PyCharm

Comment: Can confirm that this solution works for PyCharm 2021.1.1

Comment: May I ask why it works?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and try the other answer below first https://stackoverflow.com/a/69284831/3901029  It takes a long time to reindex big project

Answer (score 19):

This also happened to me and the cause was that the project folder was removed from the 'project structure'. You can re-add it in `Settings`-> `Project <...>` -> `Project Structure`.

[image: Settings-> Project <...> -> Project Structure.]

See also the documentation:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html

Comment: I had this issue in PyCharm and this solution worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

The above solution did not work for me -- by happenstance, I was clicking around the settings in Intellij/GoLand and stumbled across a solution that worked for me.

When I went to the Project Structure, the Project Structure pane was empty and there was no way for me to manually re-add my project directory.

Fix that worked for me:
`Top Menu Bars -> File -> Repair IDE`

A bubble window shows up on the bottom right, and I just clicked through the tooltips to repair different aspects of Intellij. In my case, the 'Reindex Project Structure" step worked for me (it was Step 3 of 6 in the repair process).

After repairing + waiting a bit for the project to reindex, everything went back to normal.

Comment: Worked for me on WebStorm 2021.3.3! Thank you, @Steven

Comment: had to delete .idea first

Comment: First time for me that a "Repair stuff" link actually repairs stuff within a few seconds (and yet I used Microsoft OS for a few years)

Answer (score -1):

As @Framester points out, the project source is missing from the IDE config.

Right clicking on project root  you can add that as a Source

Select:

- `Mark Directory As` -> `Sources Root`

[image]

Comment: Not wokring any more... they have remove this option